# URL my-web-url.com vs myweburl.com in SEO

Tags: url, seo

Can anyone suggest about the different between two domain in Search engine and it's effect. although there are two different words in the domain most prefer domain without "-" but in my knowledge "-" means space in the URL and "_" means same words but this two symbols are least use in domain name. Can anyone provide the different on these two.

Comment: I read many stuff about SEO, but never about the domain name... So far +1 good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One should first give priority to the domain name without '-' because it is hard to pronounce when telling someone your domain name, as well as chances are high that people will often forget '-' in your domain name when they are typing, at least the first few times. Of course this will impact your business negatively.

Also, the domain with hyphen doesn't produces very good feeling in the customer as well. Agree with what @chimpsarehungry said in the earlier answer.

Other than that, I guess it doesn't matters much in the SEO though. May be even produces good effect in some cases as in long URLs. For eg. WordPress posts. URL's with '-' are search engine friendly.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look for yourself, based on 2011 data gathered by SEOmoz:

http://www.seomoz.org/article/search-ranking-factors#metrics

Not looking so good for dashes. Some of that is from correlation of spammers using such domains, but definitely not all of it. I apologize I don't have a reference to back this up, but there was a Matt Cutts QA where he said multiple dashes is indicative of spam and does indeed get a negative hit in overall rank score. I believe it was part of a big keynote speech so it'd be hard to find. You'll just have to take my word for it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will matter at all. But as a search engine user the sites with dashes in between them look spam-like to me. Name one popular website with a dash.

Comment: penny-arcade.com Alexa rank of 5,194 globally and 2,135 in the US.